# How can I fix an issue bootstrapping dictionary data using ng-intit on the View and a ViewBag object from and MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, dictionary

I am having an issue bootstrapping data from a serialized dictionary from a MVC controller.

My controller is doing saving the serialized object like this:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            test.Add("A","1");
            test.Add("C","3");

            ViewBag.SetupDataCollectionMapping = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

My vie is using n-init like this

```
 <div id="SetupContainerDv" data-ng-init="metricMeasureMap = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.SetupDataCollectionMapping)"></div>
```

But I am having an issue view related to parsing the object

Issue

```
Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: metricMeasureMap = {
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.24/$parse/ueoe?p0=metricMeasureMap%20%3D%20%7B
   at Parser.prototype.peekToken (http://localhost:50835/scripts/angular.js:10551:7)
   at Parser.prototype.object (http://localhost:50835/scripts/angular.js:10887:5)
   at Parser.prototype.primary (http://localhost:50835/scripts/angular.js:10514:7)
   at Parser.prototype.unary (http://localhost:50835/scripts/angular.js:10767:7)
   at Parser.prototype.multiplicative (http://localhost:50835/scripts/angular.js:10750:5)
   at Parser.prototype.additive (http://localhost:50835/scripts/angular.js:10741:5)
   at Parser.prototype.relational (http://localhost:50835/scripts/angular.js:10732:5)
   at Parser.prototype.equality (http://localhost:50835/scripts/angular.js:10723:5)
   at Parser.prototype.logicalAND (http://localhost:50835/scripts/angular.js:10714:5)
   at Parser.prototype.logicalOR (http://localhost:50835/scripts/angular.js:10702:5) <div id="SetupContainerDv"
```